# Reading from a gigabyte file

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream

For a large file or piped stream, a buffer-backed solution (BufferedInputStream/ByteArrayInputStream) is obviously not the way to go.  Would appreciate if someone can tell me the recommended approach to deal with such a situation.

I can think of this - but may not be the best or most efficient approach out there:

```
public class Streams {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream reader=null;
    try{
      try {
        reader=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/file"));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        throw e1;
      }
      while(true) {
        try {
          byte a=reader.readByte();
        } 
        catch(EOFException e) {
          //consume
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          //throw
          throw e;
        }
        //do something
      }
    }
    finally {
      try {
        reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you think buffered streams will not help?

Comment: Just don't read one byte at a time, if you read blocks of say 4 - 256 KB, you will be able to read as fast as your hard drive can give you the data. At this point, the only way to read the data faster is to get a faster hardware (or only read data which is already in memory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with using `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedReader` for large files.  In fact, if you need to read / process the files a byte or character at a time, this is a natural approach.  And if you are performing a significant amount of "work" on the bytes / characters after you have read them (i.e. this application's bottleneck is not reading the input stream), then buffered streams are likely to be just fine.

On the other hand, using a `ByteArrayInputStream` is a poor choice for two reasons:

- You need to load (or map) the entire file into memory *before* you can create the `ByteArrayInputStream`.
- There is an upper bound of 2^31 bytes on the size of a byte array ... that's 2Gb.

---

<strike>In fact, your proposed version with a `DataInputStream` is not materially different from using a `BufferedInputStream`.  A `DataInputStream` uses an internal buffer in much the same way as a `BufferedInputStream` does.</strike>

My memory was incorrect.  In fact `DataInputStream.readByte()` is unbuffered.  So your proposed version is going to be a lot slower than a version that uses `BufferedInputStream`.  Basically, each `readByte()` call in your version will do a syscall.  That's going to make reading very, very slow.

---

The only way you could get a significant speed-up is to read the file using the NIO `Buffer` and `Channel` APIs.  These APIs reduce the amount of in-memory copying that happens ... compared with the classical APIs.  The downside is that these APIs are more awkward to use.

And this presupposes that reading the input file *is* the main bottleneck.

Comment: So,the only reason why or where you would use a ByteArrayInputStream is when you really want the entire stream in memory,before actually processing?Possibly,the idea would be use mark and reset features to re-play the stream in-memory(pretty much similar to an xml DOM).

Comment: I can think of other reasons ... potentially ... but basically it only makes sense to use a BAIS if there is something about your application that requires a BAIS.  It is not a viable strategy for handling big files.

Comment: According to the Java source code, `DataInputStream.readByte()` is unbuffered. It's the UTF reading functions that have a small buffer of 80 bytes, though.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with wrapping the `FileInputStream` in a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html). According to the Java library source code, the default buffer size is a mere 8192 bytes, so you won't run out of memory from using this.

In your current code, each call of `DataInputStream.readByte()` will call `FileInputStream.read()`, which is a slow native function that goes to C and the operating system.

Instead, you should wrap the `FileInputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` with a buffer size of several hundred kilobytes. That way, `DataInputStream.readByte()` will call `BufferedInputStream.read()`, which is reasonably fast (and implemented in pure Java).